# Joining two columns (type date, and type string) into another column in the same table (type timestamp) in PostgreSQL

Tags: string, postgresql, date, timestamp

I am having problems updating my table 'appointments' in postgreSQL. The table has a column date (type date) and a column time (type string). I need to join these two columns, and insert the value into a column starts_at (type timestamp) in the same table 'appointments'. I am having problems with finding the appropriate syntax to achieve that.

Any ideas?

Kind regards.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the time value is a properly formatted ISO time (e.g. `'19:45:38'`), you can cast it to a `time` value and add it to the `date` value to get a `timestamp`:

```
update appointments
    set starts_at = the_date_column + cast(the_time_column as time)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the column time (type string) saves time as HH:MM (example: '10:45'). 

I have tried your proposed solution, and as you warned, I got an error "ERROR: invalid input syntax for type time: "Invalid date" "

Comment: `cast('10:45' as time)` works just fine, the seconds are optional. If you get an error, you have some other problem with the data

Comment: You were correct, there were some entries that didn't have appropriate data, so I had to adjust the statement a bit for my specific case. Thank you so much for your help.